Can $L^p([0,1])$ be built up from countably infnite copies of $l^p({F})$ , where $F$ is a finite set or $\mathbb{N}$?
I know that $L^p([0,1])$ is not isometrically isomorphic to  $l^p(\mathbb{N})$ when $p\neq 2$? But, there is an isometric copy of $l^p(\mathbb{N})$ inside $L^p([0,1])$. My question is that whether $L^p([0,1])$ can be written as an infinite direct/tensor  product of  $l^p(\mathbb{N})$ or $L^p([0,1])$ can be built up from countably infinite copies of $l^p(\mathbb{N})$?
Since $[0,1]$ is measurably isomorphic to $2^\mathbb{N}$ with product measure, I am feeling that $L^p([0,1])$ is isometrically isomorphic to infinite tensor product of $ \mathbb{C}^2$ with $l^p$-norm. Is this statement correct?

It is correct if you define “infinite tensor product” in a correct way and equip it with the appropriate norm.

The $L^p$ tensor product of $L^p(X,\mu)$ with $L^p(Y,\nu)$ is usually DEFINED to be $L^p(X\times Y,\mu\times \nu)$. If you extend this to infinite products you get just what you know; namely, the $L^p$ infinite tensor product of $\ell^p(2)$ is $ L^p({0,1}^{\aleph_0})$ with the product measure when ${0,1}$ has the uniform probability measure. That is, you end up with $L^p$ of the Cantor group, which is isometrically isomorphic to $L^p(0,1)$.

@BillJohnson Maybe an interesting question to ask is whether the $L^p$ tensor product norm can be defined abstractly. I'd assume maybe the following norm on the algebraic tensor product $L^p(X, \mu) \otimes L^p(Y, \nu)$ matches the $L^p$ tensor norm: $|x|p^p = \inf{\sum{i=1}^n |f_i|^p|g_i|^p: x = \sum_{i=1}^n f_i \otimes g_i}$. (It is at least true when $p = 1$, if I recall correctly.)

@BillJohnson :  How does one define an  'infinite tensor product' rigorously ?

@ DavidGao : How does one define an 'infinite tensor product' rigorously?

@JohnDepp You need to fix a unit vector for each space (in this case the constant function $1$) and then consider simple tensors with all but finitely many components $1$. Equip the space of finite linear combinations of such simple tensors with the $L^p$ tensor product norm and then complete it.

I retract my previous comment suggesting maybe $L^p$ tensor product norm can be defined via that specific inf formula. I just realized that formula does not even work when $p = 2$. But still, it is interesting whether the $L^p$ tensor product norm could be defined in some intrinsic way, without writing down the measure spaces. (After all, it can be done in case of $p = 1$ and $p = 2$. The former projective tensor norm, the latter Hilbert space tensor norm. Maybe when $1 \leq p \leq 2$, one can do this via some interpolation? Then for $p > 2$ by dualizing from the $p < 2$ case?)
